# How do I Attach or update a timestamp querystring parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach a timestamp to my querystring in order to ensure that the browser bypasses its cache when I refresh the page via javascript.  I need to account for an existing querystring (which might already have a timestamp parameter in it) and for the hash tag (`http://www.example.com/?ts=123456#example`).

I have written my own implementation but I suspect that its unnecessarily complicated.  Is there a quick-and-easy or at least elegant way of accomplishing this?

Comment: can you post your implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For manipulating the query string parameters I recommend you this plugin:

- [query-object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)

It's very easy to use:

```
var timestamp = $.query.get('ts'); // get a value

window.location = $.query.set('ts', newValue); // set a value and navigate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newLocation = window.location.href.replace(/\?.*(ts=\d*)/, "ts=" + new Date().valueOf());
```