# Random Querystring to avoid IE caching

Tags: html, query-string

It is a well known problem that IE caches too much of html, even when giving a `Cache-Control: no-cache` or `Last-Modified` header to everypage.

This behaiviour is really troubling when working with querystrings to get dynamic information, as IE considers it to be the *same page* (i.e.: `http://example.com/?id=10`) and serves the cached version.

I've solved it adding either a random number or a timestring to the querystring ([as others have done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233904/howto-attach-or-update-a-timestamp-querystring-parameter)) like this `http://example.com/?id=10&t=2009-08-06_13:12:56` that I just ignore serverside.

Is there a better option? Is there another, cleaner way to acomplish this? I'm aware that `POST` isn't cached, but it is semanticaly correct to use `GET` here.

Comment: What I'm asking: is there any *other way* of doing this?

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect, by the way. IE doesn't "cache too much of HTML". See www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf for discussion of caching in IE.

Comment: @Eric, IE has some unexpected/inconsistent [behavior](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222064/) [regarding caching](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067).

Comment: using the generic $.ajax as suggested in the above post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1767342/5969842 helped solve the issue without using a random number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in the end, the only reliable way to do this (thanks to IE6) is using a 
[random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234246/random-querystring-to-avoid-ie-caching/1234260#1234260), 
or 
[time bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234246/random-querystring-to-avoid-ie-caching/1234282#1234282) 
querystring.

You could use a 
[time bound querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234246/random-querystring-to-avoid-ie-caching/1234282#1234282) 
that only changes every 15 seconds (or any other amount of time), so you'd lower the server hit count, as you'd see locally cached content for those 15 seconds.

If you have 
[a](http://www.apple.com/safari/) 
[standard](http://www.getfirefox.com) 
[compliant](http://www.google.com/chrome) 
[browser](http://www.opera.com), you can get away with only using 
[ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP%5FETag).

Comment: This again will fail if the user comes back to the page using the back button and does a refresh on the page. Were you able to find a sure-shot solution which works in all cases? Thanks.

Comment: You generate the "random" part of the querystring with javascript clientside like shown on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234246/random-querystring-to-avoid-ie-caching/1234260#1234260 That way, it will be different *every time* the `get` or `post` is done.

Comment: " ...(thanks to IE6) is ..." thanks to IE7 too, I did not test IE8 yet.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you are using jQuery, instead of using $.get or $.getJson, use the more generic $.ajax and explicitly set the cache value to false. The following is an example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
                         alert("success");
                 }
    });
```

A little more code required (not much though) than using .getJson or .get but will solve the problem cleanly without appending random numbers.

Comment: i got to find that using GET request in IE we should set the not to cache the html and i set 'cache: false' and that prevented IE from bringing the result from cache..thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the current Unix Time in milliseconds to avoid the problem of many requests in one second (it is much less likely to have multiple requests in one millisecond)

```
var url = "http://whatever.com/stuff?key=value&ie=" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a random number (not timestamp) on the querystring, or actually changing the filename are the two methods recommended. Steve Souders and [YAHOO!'s performance group](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/) has published a *ton* of useful information and practices they've discovered and developed while optimizing one of the world's most heavily-visited properties.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but take care, in one second there can be many requests. This is why I use this:

```
$.getJSON("http://server/example?param=value&dummy=" + Math.random(), ...);
```

Comment: Well, I don't want the **same client** hitting my server **several timer per second**, so I don't mind if the information showed is 1 second old. Of course, the output is plain text for humans.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header in the response?
You might use a random one, or a checksum of the generated page so that the cached version is served when appropriate.

I'm not sure what's the behaviour of IE, but with recent versions it should work.

See also the [HTTP RFC section on ETag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19)