# Clear XML cache for Flash player

Tags: xml, flash, slideshow

I'm using the [SlideShowPro](http://slideshowpro.net) player to display my pictures and videos. The issue I'm having is when I update my pictures/video, the website stills shows the old content until I reset the browser cache. Is there a way I can reset the cache on the server so when I update the XML file, it automatically shows the new content for all the users?

Comment: Keep in mind SWF uses browser as the vehicle to get the XML's in your case, so it is the browser that caches the data, not the Flash.  If you just go to the browser and type in the URL of the XML, you would get the cached content.  Sunil D.'s solution should help avoid it.  In your situation, perhaps expiring the content on the server-side would be easier.

Comment: How do I expire content from the server side?

Comment: What kind of server technology do you use?  ASP, ASP.NET, PHP or JSP?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this. They all have the drawback of making the browser download the file everytime, regardless of whether it has changed.

1. [Use HTTP headers to tell the browser not to cache the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers).
2. Add a [random query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234246/random-querystring-to-avoid-ie-caching) to the URL for the XML file. For example, add the "epoch time" (time in seconds/milliseconds since 1970):

`http://myServer.com/myXmlUrl.xml?time=120001033`

Comment: Great! You might want to google for IE specific solutions. This is quite a common problem :)