# Why does one of my pngs have a query string attached?

Tags: png, query-string

I'm not using any WP cache plug ins. I've noticed that only one png out of the other pngs (and other images) I have on my WP site has a query string attached to it when I look at in Chrome dev tools. It's actually downloaded twice - with and without query string.

The other odd this is that Chrome Dev tools says that the intiator for the png with query string is jQuery. I just include jQuery from Google's CDN, so I'm not changing anything.

Any ideas to why just one of my pngs (why this one?) has a query string attached? Here's what it looks like:

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/myTheme/images/slide1Btn.png?1369071380764" alt="">
```

Please let me know if I haven't included enough information.

**Edit**
This png is a button on one of the slides I have in a slideshow. I use http://archive.slidesjs.com/ to generate the slideshow. The png images are part of the HTML markup and not generated by the script, however I did find this line in the slides.js code:

```
// gets image src, with cache buster
    var img = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src') + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

I would like to just have the png load once and just be retrieved from the cache on reloads - like each of the pngs will do on subsequent slides in my slideshow. I'm perplexed as to why it only happens to this png.

Answer (score 1):

It might either be :

- some argument for a script that dynamically generates or resizes or processes the image (it does not matter that the url has a `.png` extension, that doesn't necessarily mean that a png file  is served statically)
- a "[cache breaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234246/random-querystring-to-avoid-ie-caching/1234282)" - or "cache buster". This can be used to prevent the browser (sometimes also the server) to get the image from a cache, and force it to get it fresh from the server.

Because in this case this looks as a timestamp (unix epoch in milliseconds), I'd bet for the later.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me some more hints when you mentioned cache breaker. I've edited my qustion with more information.

Comment: Well, as you've already found, that's an implementation detail in slidesjs library, in case you object to it, you should ask them https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/slidesjs

Comment: Ok, I'll check there and report back here with an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

wordpress generates many of the images dynamically, meaning when you access the png you are calling a server page that generates the png dynamically choosing between different images or based on the query string parameters, like size for exmaple.

200px width image.

```
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Giant_water_bugs_on_plate.png&w=200&h=446&zc=1&q=100
```

vs

600px width image

```
http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Giant_water_bugs_on_plate.png&w=800&h=446&zc=1&q=100
```