# stylesheet linked with question mark and numeric value

Tags: css

I can see this `site.com/assets/css/screen.css?954d46d92760d5bf200649149cf28ab453c16e2b`what is this random alpha numeric vales question mark ? i don't think it's taking some value to use or what is it about ?
**edit** : also on refreshing page the alpha-numeric value is same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634123/what-does-the-question-mark-at-then-end-of-a-css-include-url-do

Comment: Its probably a cahebuster. When a server encounters `?anything` it will try to send this to the requested page and wait for a response, that way you are certain to get the most recent file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for preventing the browser from caching the CSS. When a CSS is requested by some browsers, specifically Internet Explorer, the browser will have a local copy of the CSS.

When a request is given to a server as:

```
site.com/assets/css/screen.css?skdjhfk
site.com/assets/css/screen.css?5sd4f65
site.com/assets/css/screen.css?w4rtwgf
site.com/assets/css/screen.css?helloWd
```

The server at `site.com` sees only:

```
site.com/assets/css/screen.css
```

And gives the latest version. But when the HTML page is requesting the browser to fetch the CSS as: `site.com/assets/css/screen.css`, for the first time, it fetches from the `site.com` server. There are many possibilities that the content might be changed in the meantime when the next request is sent. So programmers generally add a `?and-some-random-text`, which is called **Query String**. This will **force** the browser to get a new copy from the server.

**Some more detailed explanation:**

> It is a well known problem that IE caches too much of html, even when
>   giving a `Cache-Control: no-cache` or `Last-Modified` header to
>   everypage.
>
> This behaiviour is really troubling when working with querystrings to
>   get dynamic information, as IE considers it to be the *same page*
>   (i.e.: `http://example.com/?id=10`) and serves the cached version.
>
> I've solved it adding either a random number or a timestring to the
>   querystring ([as others have done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233904/howto-attach-or-update-a-timestamp-querystring-parameter)) like this
>   `http://example.com/?id=10&t=2009-08-06_13:12:56` that I just ignore
>   serverside.
>
> Is there a better option? Is there another, cleaner way to acomplish
>   this? I'm aware that `POST` isn't cached, but it is semanticaly
>   correct to use `GET` here.

Reference: [Random Querystring to avoid IE caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234246/random-querystring-to-avoid-ie-caching)